# 'lstlisting' inside a table cell ignores line breaks

Tags: tabulary, lstlisting

I am trying to put code listings within a tabulary cell. It works fine for the most part except that `lstlisting` is merging all lines into a single line. The MWE shows the problem. Any idea how it can be done?

Reason for using `tabulary`, I need four things in a table:

- ability to break lines,
- multicolumns,
- code listing,
- and automatic adjustment of line width.

I have tried using `tabular`, `tabularx` but neither of them comes close to what I am able to do using `tabulary`. There are only two pending issues with `tabulary`:

1. listing is not breaking lines
2. I am unable to display the pipe character! (I am not sure whether this pipe char issue is something that can be answered here or requires a fresh stackexchage post. Apologies if it does.)

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{bred}{rgb}{0.80,0,0}


\lstdefinestyle{Xcode} {
    language        = Java,
    basicstyle      = footnotesizettfamily,
    showspaces      = false,
    showstringspaces = false,
    breakautoindent = true,
    flexiblecolumns = true,
    keepspaces      = true,
    stepnumber      = 0,
    xleftmargin     = 0pt}

\lstset{
    style = Xcode,
    breaklines=false,
    frame=single,
   basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
   numbers=none,
   numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
   keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3,
  escapeinside={(*}{*)},
  breaklines=true
}


\let\oldtexttt\texttt% Store \texttt

\usepackage{tabulary}

\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\renewcommand{\texttt}[2][black]{\sloppy \textcolor{#1}{\ttfamily #2}}% \texttt[<color>]{<stuff>}

\usepackage{datetime}

\begin{document}
Dummy text here.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|L|L|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Dummy Heading 1}}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{\linewidth}|}{Dummy description 1. Test  \textbf{bold} aaa aaaa aaa \texttt[blue]{tt blue} bbb bbbb}\\ \hline
Colum1 Header(s) & Description and Examples etc\\ \hline
\textbf{+, -, *, /, PIPECHAR}
\newline (Binary) \newline
Unable to display pipe character here
& \textbf{Addition, subtraction, multiplication,} and \textbf{division}.\newline \newline Example:\newline 

I want to put code listing in this cell as follows. But all lines are being merged into a single line.
\begin{lstlisting}[language=java, basicstyle={\small\ttfamily}, moredelim={[is][\color{red}]{STARTRC}{ENDRC}}]^^J
int a = 10;
Integer b = 100; //using primitive wrapper here
int c = a + b;
\end{lstlisting} 
I am using texttt on each line as altertive but this alternative cannot highlight language syntax
\texttt{int a = 10;}\newline
Integer b = 100; //using primitive wrapper here\newline
int c = a + b;\newline

other text here \\ \hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{center}

The same listing works fine outside the table :

\begin{lstlisting}[language=java, basicstyle={\small\ttfamily}, moredelim={[is][\color{red}]{STARTRC}{ENDRC}}]
int a = 10;
Integer b = 100; //using primitive wrapper here
int c = a + b;
\end{lstlisting}
 \end{document}
```

Here is how it looks:
[image: lstlising merged multiple lines into one]

Comment: You have to add `breaklines=true` to `listings` where you want to break lines automatically. This value is false for default.

Comment: note also that lstlisting is a verbatim environment so basically does not work inside tabulary, you would be better to put the code fragments in extrenal files and use listings input command

Comment: @Ignasi I do have breaklines=true in lstset definition (see the last line of my lstset in mwe. Is this the right location or you meant somewhere else. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately, I have a quite a lot of listings. Putting them in a file of their own would not be practical for me so I would like to avoid that if possible. Also, when you says lstlising "does not work" within tabulary, do you mean it should error out? because it is compiling and generating output. The only issue is that it is ignoring newline. Could this be a bug in lstlisting or may be I need to put some special escape sequence in this particular case? thank you.

Comment: You're right, I mistook the question. The problem is that `listings` doesn't respect newlines inside `tabulary`. As I didn't carefully read code and compared with results, I thought you wanted to break long lines.

Comment: It only works in your example as the content is (from the view of tex) not really special. You would get errors is you added e.g. a command like `\section`. You could put all your snippets in one external file and use line markers to select the one you want See 6.7 Arbitrary linerange markers in the listings documentation.

Comment: Two further options: (a) render the listing into an `lrbox` before the table and then use the box. (b) use `\lstinputlisting` but create the file on-the-fly before the table with the `filecontents’ package.

Comment: it is not a bug but a well documeted rule that verbatim commands do not work in the argumnents of other commands or in special envronments such as tabularx/tabulary. newline is not the only issue none of lisstings handling of charaacters can work in such a context.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. will work accordingly. This being my first question on stackexchange, I am not sure what is the right course of action for me now.