# Table column does not fit

Tags: tables, tabularx, verbatim

I am using the tabularx package and as per previous answer this should sort by problem of having a table where rows are too wide. My understanding was this will wrap the texts and it would fit in. But actually this is going beyond the page width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}% for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule etc macros
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \RaggedRight macro


\title{examle}

\author{An example from Overleaf}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\listoftables

%% create a derivative column type called 'L':
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1.5em}X}

\vspace{1cm}
% \newcolumntype{b}{X}
% \newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}
\begin{table*}
    \caption{example}
    \label{tab:code-example}
    \centering
    % \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
    \begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{XX}
    \toprule  % replaced all \hline commands with rules from the booktabs package
    \upshape  Representation of the code & Code \\    
    \midrule
Representation 1    
& \verb|ID math . ID1 calculateSomethingAwesome ( LIT 100 , LIT 200, LIT 300 )| \\ 
Another representation name that can be very very long
& \verb|ID math . ID1 calculateSomethingAwesome ( LIT 100 , INTEGER 200, LIT 300 )| \\ 
Representation 3 
& \verb|ID math . ID1 calculateSomethingAwesome ( FLOAT 100 , NUMERIC 200, LIT ID 300 )| \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*} 



\end{document}
```

Comment: First off, your code currently contains a syntax error: `\hline` *must* occur inside a `tabular`-like or `array`-like environment; did you maybe mean to run `\hrule`? Second, the use of `\verb|...|` in table's second column basically defeats the purpose of using `X` columns. Please explain why  you're using `\verb`, i.e., what it is that you ultimately wish to accomplish in terms of formatting.

Comment: I am trying to do inline code listing in with the \verb, that's the reason I am using \verb. I like the way code is displayed with \verb, that's the sole reason of using verb

Comment: Unrelated to the question itself, but please clean up your preamble. Currently, you load several packages more than once. Please remove the duplicates.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436383/lstlisting-inside-a-table-cell-ignores-line-breaks#comment1094961_436383 might be interesting to have a look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verbatim text is to long that can be fit in table. I may be solution that instead `\verb` you use `\ttfamily` font and enable, that text in second column cab be broken in more lines.:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{example}
\label{tab:code-example}
    \centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L
                                >{\hsize=1.2\hsize\ttfamily}L
                             @{}}
    \toprule  %
Representation of the code & Code   \\
    \midrule
Representation 1
    & ID math.ID1 calculateSomethingAwesome (LIT 100, LIT 200, LIT 300)\\
Another representation name that can be very very long
    & ID math.ID1 calculateSomethingAwesome (LIT 100, INTEGER 200, LIT 300) \\
Representation 3
    & ID math.ID1 calculateSomethingAwesome (FLOAT 100, NUMERIC 200, LIT ID 300)\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: here you have used hsize 0.8 and 1.2, together they are `0.8+1.2=2`, should the parts match up to 1? Sorry I just trying to understand/

Comment: @Exploring, sum had to be (i) integer, and (ii) equal to number of the `X` columns in table. For details see `tabularx` documentation, subsection 
 *4.3 Column widths* on page 3.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a closer look at the warnings you get upon compiling your document, you can find

```
\verb may be unreliable inside tabularx
```

This already gives a hint on why your table still overflows into the margins, although you used `tabularx`. To overcome this, you can use `\lstinline` in combination with the `breaklines=true` option from the `listings` package, which you already load in your preamble. The font that is used for the code can of course be adjusted using appropriate options inside of `\lstset`.

The following MWE contains two different versions of your table, one using `tabularx`, the other a regular `tabular` with `p` type columns. Both are as wide as the textwidth. In the example, I have also commented out unneccessary packages and added an explanation why I removed each package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} not needed since this is the default with an up-to-date installation
%\usepackage{array} not needed since internally loaded by tabularx
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{array,booktabs} Do not load packages more than once.
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{color} better to use xcolor instead
%\usepackage{tabularx} Do not load packages more than once.
%\usepackage{multirow} Do not load packages more than once.
%\usepackage{lscape}  Do not load packages more than once.
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{array} Do not load packages more than once.
%\usepackage{wrapfig} Do not load packages more than once.
%\usepackage{booktabs} Do not load packages more than once.
%\usepackage{tabularx} Do not load packages more than once.
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \RaggedRight macro
\usepackage{booktabs}


\lstset{breaklines=true}

\title{ContextML Tables For the ICSE Submission}

\author{An example from Overleaf}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\listoftables


\begin{table}
    \caption{example}
    \label{tab:code-example}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{XX}
    \toprule  % replaced all \hline commands with rules from the booktabs package
    \upshape  Representation of the code & Code \\    
    \midrule
Representation 1    
& {\lstinline|ID math . ID1 calculateSomethingAwesome ( LIT 100 , LIT 200, LIT 300 )|} \\ 
Another representation name that can be very very long
& {\lstinline|ID math . ID1 calculateSomethingAwesome ( LIT 100 , INTEGER 200, LIT 300 )|} \\ 
Representation 3 
& {\lstinline|ID math . ID1 calculateSomethingAwesome ( FLOAT 100 , NUMERIC 200, LIT ID 300 )|} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table} 


\begin{table}
    \caption{example}
    \label{tab:code-example}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
                    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.65\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
    \toprule  % replaced all \hline commands with rules from the booktabs package
    \upshape  Representation of the code & Code \\    
    \midrule
Representation 1    
& {\lstinline|ID math . ID1 calculateSomethingAwesome ( LIT 100 , LIT 200, LIT 300 )|} \\ 
Another representation name that can be very very long
& {\lstinline|ID math . ID1 calculateSomethingAwesome ( LIT 100 , INTEGER 200, LIT 300 )|} \\ 
Representation 3 
& {\lstinline|ID math . ID1 calculateSomethingAwesome ( FLOAT 100 , NUMERIC 200, LIT ID 300 )|} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```